# PDFBox: Change page number of exisiting field in the document

Tags: java, certificate, pdfbox, digital-signature

How I can change the page number of existing field in the pdf document using PDFBox. I have tried following code but it did n't work

```
public static void changePageNumberOfField(PDDocument document, String fieldName, int pageNumber) {
        PDField field = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(null).getField(fieldName);
        PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNumber);

        for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : field.getWidgets()) {
            widget.setPage(page);
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me the way to solve this?

Comment: The field you set is an optional field that is hardly used when displaying a pdf. You essentially have to remove the widget of the form field from the *Annotations* of the page it currently is on. Then you have to add the widget to the *Annotations* of the new page. As an extra you should set the page of the widget like you did.

Comment: @mkl can you please provide some code example